# How to dynamically generate a JS function and store it on a variable?

Tags: javascript

Let's say you generate the body of JS function dynamically or you retrieve it from a database and you want to generate the relevant functions and assign it to the property of an object.

So far I have tried `eval()` but apart from assigning the function to the value it also executes it. Is there a better way?

Comment: What did you try exactly? Show us some code, please!

Comment: Generating JS source code from strings is a terrible idea. You should never do that. Maybe you just need a closure. You haven't described your problem in enough detail to tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* use the [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) constructor, **but don't**:

```js
var function_body = "var d = b + c; return a + d;";
var my_function = new Function("a", "b, c", function_body);
console.log(my_function(2, 4, 6));  // 12
```

**This is a terrible idea**; `eval` is evil, introducing many, many security vulnerabilities pretty much wherever it's used. Any form of `eval` should be avoided like the plague.

Comment: `eval` by any other name is just as painful to debug and at risk of introducing security issues.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning Function, I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: @Karapapas Well, now you know. But don't use it please; find another way. Seriously. You'll thank me later when you're not having to deal with the fallout of a security vulnerability. Listen to Quentin.

Comment: Users won't have a form to submit anything relevant to this procedure. This is for an admin panel which will be used internally.

Comment: Are your admin users are incapable of accidentally writing code that won't compile and immune to being tricked into posting malicious code.

Comment: @Karapapas More potential security holes means it's more likely that they connect in such a way that somebody can tunnel from the outside riiiight in. That `eval` or pseudo-`eval` might be their way into the Admin panel and so into your internal system.